# An exclamation point is added to the path of the document I try to open from the jar file after exporting

Tags: java, eclipse, path, export

So I have this program with a JMenuItem. When I click on this MenuItem a document (.pdf) should open, and **it does** as long as I work **in Eclipse**. However, after exporting my project in a Runnable Jar File, when I click on the MenuItem it throws this exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: file:**\C:\Users\luca\Documents\CoreoMaker\MyJarReleases\CoreoMaker_1.2.3.jar!\wls\trek\coreo\reg24.pdf** doesn't exist.

I don't know why but as you can see there is an exclamation point in the path, which clearly shouldn't be there, that causes this exception.

There is no need for code I think, because as I said before the document opens in Eclipse, it doesn't work after exporting the project.

EDIT: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. When I say I want to open the document I mean literally open that .pdf with an external application (in this case AdobeReader), not just reading its content.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the PDF within the jar file itself?

Comment: yes it's in the same folder of the project files

Comment: plus, i looked in the /bin folder and the file is there, it's just that exclamation point in the path the problem

Comment: Then don't access it as a file but rather as a resource. This issue has been answered many times on this site -- please search.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `!` -- you're trying to access it as a file.